# How to transfer files from my pixel 3a to PC

Tags: windows-10, usb, phone

I have a pixel 3a and need to ransfer some files on my phone to my PC. However, when i attempt to plug in the charger to my PC so my PC finds it as a USB device, it says the phone is entirely empty and thinks it has no files in it. That is, of course, false. It is not to do with how phones have different file systems as my PC can interact with my kindle file 7 just fine, so what is going on? I've tried using different cables and none work. When I connect the USB my phone doesn't do anything about it and explorer says "This directory is empty" as if it were an empty folder. There are no USB options on my phone.

Comment: Does your phone use a stock ROM (original unmodified) from Google? What do you mean by "no files" what do you see if you connect the phone via USB to your PC in Windows Explorer?

Comment: And as soon as you connect it, the phone should show a menu with different options to connect. What options are shown and which one are you selecting?

Comment: Plug it in. On the phone Setting - Connected Devices - USB - and choose what you want to happen. Not a Windows 10 question at all.

Comment: The phone uses a stock ROM, and it simply displays a "This folder is empty" message when I try. The phone dos not recognise anything either